# USB 3.0 port is not detecting USB 2.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-3, usb-2

I have two USB ports, one for USB 2.0 and the other one for USB 3.0. They worked normally until the USB 3.0 port stopped detecting the USB 2.0 flash drive, mice, keyboard, etc.

But it still detects USB 3.0 normally! And I have tried many solutions for that I looked for, but none of them worked.
(Only formatting the laptop I haven't tried yet.)

PS: I have Windows 10.

PS 2: The plug type for both ports is Type A.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a common problem, which is why motherboards still contain USB2 ports; however, if the USB3 port could previously detect USB2 devices it no longer can, update/reinstall the chipset drivers for the port's controller _(e.g. many motherboards use a third-party controller, such as Renesas, in conjunction with the CPU chipset, mapping some ports to the third party, others to the CPU)_. If that doesn't resolve the issue, run hardware diagnostics on the motherboard _(laptops have this built-in to the BIOS/UEFI firmware)_; To rule out an OS issue, boot a Linux LiveUSB and test.

Comment: have you tried installing the original manufacturer driver for the USB 3.0 bus device instead of allowing windows to automatically install the driver?